# Blender 2.8 Python , Bevel from shape not working

Tags: python, path, bevel, bezier-curves

I am attempting to make cords using python in Blender 2.8

Currently, I have successfully made it work when using a normal bezier curve that I modify along with a circle I added. (see image below)

My issue on a spline that I add points to and combine into a curve seems to have an issue where it will not run the bevel-using-shape option unless it is run in separate code, or done by hand. (see images below)

I'll also include my code which shouldn't need any adjustments to test. The only issue is the last line that bevels.

Thanks in advance!

[image: EX working with normal bezier curve]
[image: EX of not working script below]
[image: Same objects, just new script with the 1 line that wasn't working, but now working]

```
#Import python
import bpy
#Import vectors
from mathutils import Vector
#Import math allows access to things like pi
import math as m

#___________________________________COIL-SHAPED Start: This Script Allows a Coil-shaped spline


#Create a circle spline/bezier circle | in the center ofthe world
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(radius=0.15, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
#rename it
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "Coil_Circle"
    obj.data.name = "Coil_Circle"

# a list of coordinates for the vertices of the spline to follow
coords_list = [[0,0,0], ]

#This is how to reference a specific part of the list
#coords_list[1] = [0,0,0]


#Variables for the coil shape to follow
# n = how many to make
n = 33
# r = the distance between each one | also can be considered how whide the coil will be
r = 2
# the distance vertically from the ground
z = 0


# for loop through n
for i in range(1,n+1):
    #Add a new spot into our list
    coords_list.append([0,0,0])
    #create an angle using pi that allows for rotation
    angle = ((i-1)*4*m.pi)/n
    #the x position change of the new point
    x = r*m.cos(angle)
    #the y position of the new point
    y = r*m.sin(angle)
    #the z position (vertical)
    z = 0.01*i
    #Assign the position to the list
    coords_list[i] = [x,y,z]




# make a new curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# make a new spline in that curve
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')

# a spline point for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords_list)-1) # theres already one point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)

# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('Coil_Delete', crv)
# link the points to complete the spline curve
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)



# Deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#Select the curve
bpy.data.objects['Coil_Delete'].select_set(True)

#rename it
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "Coil_Curve"
    obj.data.name = "Coil_Curve"

#____________________________________________________This line does not seem to work when combined with this code
#select our circle as the geometry bevel object
bpy.context.object.data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["Coil_Circle"]



#Apply the modifier

#Delete circle reference

#___________________________________COIL-SHAPED END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me fix it.

**Solution:**

Change `bpy.context.object.data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["Coil_Circle"]`

To `bpy.data.objects['Coil_Curve'].data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["Coil_Circle"]`

Because now it will correctly reference the curve we made

Comment: Very useful, this pointed me at the right place in the data structure for an issue I was having!